# fragment transaction not work properly in replace

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I'm using the Fragment and tabLayout.
there is a problem. The `hystory` fragment is displayed for the first time, but not  displayed  for the second time, and other times. But the `home` fragment is working properly and displayed at any time.

```
TabLayout tabLayout;
FrameLayout frm_Content;

FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    frm_Content = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frm_content);

    final HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    final HistoryFragment historyFragment =new HistoryFragment();

    fragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frm_content, homeFragment)
                .commit();
    }


    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("home"),0);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("hystory"),1);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("region"),2);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


            switch(tab.getPosition()){
                case 0 :
                   // fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(historyFragment);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frm_content, homeFragment)
                            .commit();
                            .break();


               case 1:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frm_content, historyFragment)
                            .commit();
                            .break();

                case 2 :


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/md_blue_grey_50"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frm_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so probably your problem is that you forgot to put `break` in the cases.

In OnCreate you put the homeFragment view as the first view you see. Then clicking the tab from 0 index, you open homeFragment BUT you miss the `break` -> right after homeFragment, historyFragment is opened.

When you click historyFragment (1st position), you miss the `break` aswell, but there is no other action on next (2nd position) index, so the fragment does not change.

What you should do is put the `break` after replacing the fragments

```
           switch(tab.getPosition()){
                case 0 :
                   // fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(historyFragment);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frm_content, homeFragment)
                            .commit();
                    break;
               case 1:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frm_content, historyFragment)
                            .commit();
                    break;
                case 2 :


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final FragmentTransaction fTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
fTransaction.replace(R.id.frm_content, new NewFragment(), "NewFragmentTag"); 
fTransaction.commit();
```